# Positiong loaded object based on root stage instead of MC that is loaded from root

Tags: actionscript-3, root, stage, substage

I have a root stage, and a MC that is called from the root stage.Now from that MC, i will called in another MC2, and I wanted to placed the MC in the center of the stage. The reason I could not use normal ADDED_TO_STAGE at MC and define the center is because MC is not place in the exact position of the root stage (as in x, y=0). So if I would target MC2 at MC stage center, it would not be the exact center of the root stage/screen.

How can I called the root stage properties rather than adding MC2 into the stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [localToGlobal()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) method that will translate your nested coordinates into global position